# 3 wheeled light commercial vehicle sound

Tags: noise, engine-theory, starter

I'm new to this platform. So I'm not sure if my inquiry is appropriate to publish here. If not, kindly direct me to the appropriate forum.
I've noticed that three-wheeled commercial vehicles produce significantly more vibrations and noise when the engine is started and while travelling on the road. I am also sharing picture link for such type of vehicles .(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Piaggio_Vespacar_APE_P400V_MPF.dsc01304.jpg/1280px-Piaggio_Vespacar_APE_P400V_MPF.dsc01304.jpg)
However, neither a 2 wheel bike nor a standard 4 wheeled vehicle exhibit this problem. How can this be? Please note that I am not telling this issue for vehicles with problems , but I am speaking in general right from newly bought .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your question is pretty broad and opinion based, mainly because I'd lay hay on the fact it really depends on the manufacturer of the three wheeler. Also, not having anything like it here in the States may also cloud people's judgement. I'm not really sure this is answerable in a comprehensive way.

Answer (score 0):

Because they have simpler, cheaper engines than automobiles or even motorcycles.

An automobile will typically have at least a 3-4-cylinder engine. A 4-cylinder can run reasonably smoothly, since it has a power stroke every 180 degrees of engine rotation.  These frequent power strokes allow use of tuned ports to re-capture some of the energy in intake and exhaust pulses, which aside from improving efficiency also quiets the engine.

However, at 50-175cc, these buggies are either 1 or at most 2 cylinders. These are rougher running by nature - simply **fewer power strokes per engine rotation**.

They also may have air cooled engines. These require the **engine cylinders to be relatively exposed**, and have a strong airflow through them. This means the cylinders cannot be jacketed and enclosed, as they are on a water-cooled car.

The engines may also use a 2-stroke cycle.  This adds a complication, because without the other two strokes, intake and exhaust gases are not actively *pumped*.  The engine relies on a process called *scavenging*, and that requires a relatively "open" and **low restriction exhaust**, thus, louder.

Also, with so few cylinders it is **difficult to use "tuned ports"**, another trick used on 4 or more cylinders. Intake and exhaust air moves in pulses, and these pulses can be tuned to arrive at the port just as it's opening, helping the engine breathe. *But this also reduces intake and exhaust noise*.   With so few cylinders on these engines, this is less practical, so the staccato intake and exhaust pulses are more audible.

Comment: Most gasoline powered cars in europe have 3 cylinder engines....

Comment: @Luuklag okay. Even with 3, a 120 degree crank can be cast, 4-cycle won't run *too* clunky, and it's water cooled and tuned ports are possible. But when you're down to 175cc that's not a multicylinder engine.

Comment: From manufacturer data, 4 cylinder cars are still way more common in Europe @Luuklag, although 3 cyl engines are increasing in popularity due to their better fuel efficiency